# Change jTabbedPane alignment

Tags: jtabbedpane

I spend hours in searching about changing jTabbedPane alignment from left to right as following:

[screen shot: right alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sy1Wm.jpg)

[screen shot: left alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpGPG.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This to make tabs from right to left
look at method 
setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame Test");
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 500));

        JTabbedPane tapPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tapPane.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        tapPane.insertTab("Tab1", null, new JTextField("test"), "Tab1 tip", 0);

        frame.add(tapPane);
        frame.show();
```